# PC not starting after flashing BIOS. Only fans run at power up,

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

My PC will not start after updating the BIOS incorrectly. It does not show anything, not even the BIOS menu, when turned on. I tried changing jumpers, but nothing happened. My CMOS battery is dead .

When I turn on my PC normally, it shows the green light of the power button, but now only fans are run; there's  no power button light.

Its a 10yr old pc and always start up with old time/date.

How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: 1) When you say 'your CMOS battery is dead', do you mean you removed that battery and tested it with a voltmeter? 2) What is the make and model of the motherboard? 3) Have you let the motherboard sit 24 hours with the power supply disconnected and the CMOS battery removed? I have recovered motherboards after a failed BIOS update that way.... Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score -2):

It's **dead**. You should've properly picked the right BIOS image. Either reflash the chip with a BIOS chip programmer or buy a new motherboard. No third way.

Comment: To make the answer helpful to this and other users (we are building a Q&A infobase here), suggest you edit your answer to describe how external flashing of a BIOS chip with a programmer works, and to provide an example similar to what I found to illustrate your answer.

Comment: @Austin - You should not be asking questions in a comment.

Comment: Its bricked I flashed it with wrong img let it go replacing lithium battery will only reset current bios It needs to be reflashed I 'm gonna change the damnn motherboard.Btw Thank you all for your support @Ramhound,@Moab,@K7AAY,@Audiowerfer though u tried to answer the problem that voted -ve nevertheless Its a +ve vote from my side. I lost my brother today his body got paralyzed except fans just like stephan hawkings.I spend my whole childhood with this pc and bc of me this all happened .Rip Odin (2006-2020)